# Why .NET 4.0 hide name attribute on generated LinkButton?

Tags: html, asp.net

I noticed that LinkButton doesn't have the name attribute anymore on html generated. Why? How can I re-enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because HTML5 [says](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-constraints):

> **Additional constraints and admonitions**
>
> - [...]
> - The `name` attribute on the `a` element is obsolete. Consider putting an `id` attribute on the nearest container instead.

If you really need that attribute, you can add it "by hand" through the [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx) property of your link button.

Comment: You can also use the [`xHtmlConformance`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/10/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax.aspx) configuration to alter this behaviour by setting it to `Legacy`.